# Writing differential as section of a tensor product of bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensor-products

For a smooth map $ u : M \rightarrow N $ I am asked to show that we can write 
\begin{equation}
du = \frac{\partial u^\alpha}{\partial x^i}dx^i\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\alpha}(u),
\end{equation}
for $ u^\alpha := y^\alpha \circ u $.

I am halfway there. I can see that we can view $ du \in \Gamma (T^{*}M \otimes u^{*}(TN)) $ and so for a basis of the two, locally we must have
\begin{equation}
du = a_{i \alpha}dx^i\otimes\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\alpha}(u).
\end{equation}
but im now stuck on showing that the coefficients have the correct form, i.e. I want to finally get that 
$$ a_{i \alpha} = \frac{\partial u^\alpha}{\partial x^i}$$
and this is where I'm stuck.

edit: I also know that using the usual isomorphism of tensor products we apply our map via
$$ du(v) = (a_{i \alpha}dx^i(v))\frac{\partial}{\partial y^\alpha}(u) \in u^{*}(TN)$$

Comment: Don't overthink it. What do you get when you apply $du$ to $\partial/\partial x^i$? What is the $y^\alpha$ component of this?

Comment: hm so I know that putting in [;\partial / \partial x^j ;] will give [; a_{i \alpha} \partial / \partial y^\alpha ;] if [;i=j;] and [;0;] if [;i \neq j ;] by definition of the dual basis. So I get [;du(\partial / \partial x^j) = a_{i \alpha} \partial / \partial y^\alpha ;] but I'm still a bit lost. I know this is close though. What can I do to tie it up? (I think some of my foundations are a bit lacking here)

Comment: You need to use \$dollar signs\$ for inline math, not [; ;]. (Perhaps you have TeXtheworld or a similar extension installed and it looks fine for you; but it's a mess for anyone else.)

Comment: I think I fixed what I was trying to write

Comment: Oh and I also know $ du(\partial / \partial x^i) (f) = (\partial / \partial x^i)(f \circ u)$ which I wanted to tie into the answer but again couldnt quite make the final link

Comment: ah but also I know that $ du(\partial /\partial x^i)$ lives in $TN$ so must be some span $\beta_j \partial / \partial y^j$. Now that makes me want to say that $du(\partial / \partial x^i) = (\partial u^\alpha / \partial x^i) (\partial / \partial y^\alpha)$  which then comparing coefficients would give what I need but I'm not quite sure why that should be true. It feels correct though